# How to remove latency of UI when setting state of big array in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using `React Native` to render a `Chart`.

I have 3 custom `tabs` in my app, when sliding between them I am getting new data and apply translation animation to highlight the selected tab.

I am facing a 1 second latency when scrolling. I investigated the latency and there is one parameter in `setState()` that is causing it, which is a big array of data.

I am already using `async / await`.

I tried to put `setState()` inside a `setTimeout` but the final result isn't smooth.

Is there a way to optimize setting big array in the state ? Or play the animation inpendently from `setState()` ?

**Update**

```
await Animated.spring(translateBottomX, {
  toValue: type,
  duration: 100,
}).start();

if (segment === 1) {
  await Animated.parallel([
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabOne, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 100,
    }).start(),
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabTwo, {
      toValue: width,
      duration: 100,
    }).start(),
  ]);
} else if (segment === 2) {
  await Animated.parallel([
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabOne, {
      toValue: width,
      duration: 100,
    }).start(),
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabTwo, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 100,
    }).start(),
  ]);
} else if (segment === 3) {
  await Animated.parallel([
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabOne, {
      toValue: width,
      duration: 0,
    }).start(),
    Animated.spring(translateXBottomTabTwo, {
      toValue: width,
      duration: 100,
    }).start(),
  ]);
}

setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({
    dataAxeX
  });
}, 500);
```

// using it here

```
<XAxis
    data={dataAxeX}
    formatLabel={(_, index) => dataAxeX[index].Datetime}
    contentInset={styles.xAxisContentInset}
    svg={{
       fill: "#B6C1DF",
       ...styles.xAxisStyle,
     }}
 />
```

Comment: can't visualise what's happening without code, and a sample of your data, and knowing what's happening. I can roughly tell the problem with big data would first come from your chart rendering and animation, more than because of saving it in a state. maybe you have too much data for your chart. OR maybe, there's a undesirable loop in your components, which we can only know if you share codes.

Comment: i am sorry, i dont usually make a question without code and images, but I'm not sure if I can paste the design screenshots of the client. But the problem is that I playing an animation alongside setState of big array which cause animation to lag

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial When I remove the stateState, everything is good.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I added the code

Comment: what is dataAxeX ?

Comment: That is the data I am getting from backend

Comment: this.setState({
    dataAxeX
  }); <---- this is inside a function call I hope?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225329/discussion-between-someone-special-and-amine).

Comment: Yes it is inside aa function call whenever I slide tabs

Comment: the 1 second lag is unlikey due to data update, but because your entire chart re-renders when you update your state. React native is not very good in handling a lot of drawing and rendering

Comment: Well, alongside dataAxeX, I have other states updates that doesn't cause this issue

Comment: i question if there is a way to seperate the ui from updating the state.

Comment: well the conclusion is, setting state is usually not the bottleneck, even if it's a million objects. It is whatever that's happening after you update the state, that's the bottle neck. If your chart depend on the state, then you have to update the state to force a re-render of your chart. If you don't care about chart rerendering then you can use a normal variable. No further advises if there's no further codes. You can't solve a problem with all the codes infront of you, how can we with less than 50 line of codes?

Comment: Can you also add `useNativeDriver: true` to your animations? It improves things a bit.